# figure formatting with python

Tags: floats, python

I'm trying to use the python package to automate figure generation for figures containing multiple image files.

My output seems okay, except that the imgaes are coming out as a single column, whereas if I write the same code in straight latex it comes out as two columns. Can anyone tell me how to make the python version output the figures as a double column?

here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,python}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{python}
import os
directory = "."
extension = ".png"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(r'D:\New folder\Sean Read\visualisation examples\normalised cross sections\NC04\Axial') if file.lower().endswith("png")]
name=[]
for file in files:
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(file)
    name.append(fileName)
for file in name:
   print(r'\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/%s"}' % file)
\end{python}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the python loop puts out

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/10acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/11acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/1acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/2acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/3acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/4acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/5acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/6acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/7acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/8acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/9acs copy"}
```

If I take out the python output and insert it in the latex the output is double columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,python}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/10acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/11acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/1acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/2acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/3acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/4acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/5acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/6acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/7acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/8acs copy"}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{"D:/New folder/Sean Read/visualisation examples/normalised cross sections/NC04/Axial/9acs copy"}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you need some spacing adjustments. Since you want each figure as half of text width, I suggest you to use `\begin{figure}\centering` and also I would insert `%` at the end of each line after closing `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Hey thanks, the added % seems to have done the trick, why does this help?

Comment: When you break the code into two lines some additional horizontal space could appear between them. If you insert `%` just after the last char in the line then you make sure that the following line will be executed **exactly** after the last command in the previous line.

Comment: @Sigur You should write an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Sigur explains, adding newlines places extra spaces in the output, making it wider.  A comment character `%` at the end of the lines prevents these spaces being added.

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

a
b
c

a%
b%
c

\end{document}
```

where non-blank lines contain only the visible characters, produces

[image: Sample output]

with the uncommented line breaks in the first lines producing spaces in the output.